# Where are custom maxscript modifiers saved?

Tags: plugins, maxscript

I'm studying maxscript by reverse engineering good (.mse) custom modifiers available online. Where do I locate them after installation so I can study them?

In the name of self studying, I've looked around for different free custom modifiers for 3DSmax. My main interest lies in looking at how these modifiers were written in maxscript since seeing samples and studying good code is a great way to learn.

I've downloaded and installed a few that were from the .mse format, and sure enough they show up in my 3DS max's modifier list and they work the way they should properly.

Where im lost is ~ if I use a tool like search everything on my machine, I only get directed back to the original .mse files that i downloaded. And I dont see the names of any of these custom modifiers on the plug in manager tab in 3DS max.

So if i wanted to study the code, where can I look for them?
(other than reaching out to their original creators who have been inactive for years lol)

Many thanks
Happy new year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.mse scripts do not contain source text.
Those files are encrypted and there's no way you can see what's inside.